# Updating django-oscar catalogue via API

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-oscar

I have to develop an e-commerce website but I am a newbie and I'm lost. I decided to use django-oscar.

The products must be updated on a daily basis from an API. To do so, I suppose I have to create a few models (The client has sent me LoginModel, ProductModel, ClientorderModel and so on). So I am assuming I have to implement those models in django to create my Catalog, right?)

Once the models are implemented, I would need to run a cron job to update the catalog every day.

I do not know if SO is the correct site to ask this question, if no, please tell me in which StackExchange site I would have to ask.

Thanks in advance.